missing step in proof of open subspace of E is E
Let $X$ be un vector subspace of a metric vector space $(E,d)$.
A very classical result is that $X$ open $\Leftrightarrow X=E$.
The proof relies on:
$\vec{0}\in X$
$X$ open $\Rightarrow\exists r\in \mathbb{R}^{*+}:B(\vec{0},r)\subset X$
$e\in X^C$ then choose $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon e$ "small enough" to fit inside $B(\vec{0},r)$
With a distance which derives from a norm (which has an absolute homogeneity property $\Vert{\lambda x}\Vert=\vert\lambda\vert\Vert x\Vert)$ it's obvious but is it also true for a simpler metric $d$ which has "only" symmetry, positivity, separability and triangular inequality?
Otherwise, could a counter-example be provided?

@ThomasAndrews Thx: copy-n-paste error. Fixed.

If you don't require any compatibility between the vector space structure and the metric structure, your claim becomes trivially false.

I don't understand how this is a "missing step". Can you quote a textbook or lecture notes from where you have this claim? Usually the claim is for a normed space and not a a metric vector space (whatever that is).

The discrete topology on any vector space of positive dimension is a counterexample.  The discrete topology is metric, and the trivial subspace {0} is open in that topology.
It should be pointed out that this example also imposes the discrete topology on the scalar field (if scalar multiplication is to be continuous). If we assume a topological vector space $V$ over the real or complex numbers (with the usual topology), the desired conclusion, that the only open subspace of $V$ is all of $V$, holds.
Since scalar multiplication is continuous, then such a vector space $V$ is path connected and connected.  Now a topological vector space is also a topological group with respect to vector addition, and an open subspace of one is an open subgroup in this setting.  So a proper open subspace $X$ of $V$ would be closed. But this gives $V = X \cup X^c$ as the disjoint union of two nonempty closed subsets, so $V$ is not connected; contradiction.

No. I'm not an expert and was confused by a resource with poor wording (that mixed norms and distances). Thx.
